# How to copy Files from Network folder to Local drive and preserve permissions?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, permissions, networking, copy

Please close this question. I got what I am looking for and some are arguing it doesn't belong here.

All you have to do is zip the files on the mount and drop it in your local HD. All permissions are intact!

Is it possible?

I have a network disk mounted on Ubuntu. How do I save the files (folders and files recursively) from the network mounted disk to my local disk preserving permissions?

Thank you...

Comment: Might have better luck on serverfault.com

Comment: I thought it is a simple, common question. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `rsync -a` or `cp -p`, depending on your needs.